# Using Line Integral to Find Work done by a Force along a Curve

Tags: integration, line-integrals

[Find the work done by the force $ \boldsymbol{F}=-10y\boldsymbol{i}+4x\boldsymbol{j}$
along one loop of the curve $r=\sin(9\theta)$]

I have some trouble formatting/understanding the question.

I have it set up as something like

$\int_c\boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r}(t))\cdot \boldsymbol{r}'(t)dt$

Where the $x, y$ components of **F** are rewritten with respect to $r$ (which is equal to $\sin(9\theta)$) and $\theta$.

$ \boldsymbol{F}=-10\sin(9\theta)\sin(\theta)\boldsymbol{i}+4\sin(9\theta)\cos(\theta)\boldsymbol{j}$

with parameterization

$ \boldsymbol{r}(t)=\sin(9\theta)\cos(\theta)\boldsymbol{i}+\sin(9\theta)\sin(\theta)\boldsymbol{j}$

And then I go about to find the derivative of $\boldsymbol{r}(t)$, find the dot product, and putting everything together I integrate with respect to $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.

It gets really messy, and im pretty sure this is suppose to be an easier question. Am I doing something wrong or is there an easier way to go around solving this question?

Comment: First, you don’t want $\theta$ going in that range to get one loop. Second, do you know Green’s Theorem yet?

Comment: I do know greens theorem, but I don't think F is conservative? since dP/dy =/= dQ/dx I thought that greens theorem can not be applied here. @TedShifrin

Comment: Of course Green’s Theorem applies — and gives a nonzero integral.

Comment: The vector field has no singularities. So Green, Gauss apply. This has nothing to do with the field being conservative or not. Apart from this: it is not a bad exercise and quite doable to calculate the line integral in the way you describe it: $\int_c\boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r}(t))\cdot \boldsymbol{r}'(t)dt\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. I think I understand something now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KurtG. I have one last question. In this question it asks for 1 loop of r=sin(9theta), does that usually mean from theta 0 to pi? or 1 petal from theta 0 to pi/9?   and the integration range of r after changing to polar coordinates is from 0 to sin(9theta) right?

Comment: These are three "last" questions. :) I have one, too: you wrote "one loop of the curve $r=\sin(9\theta)$". This is not a curve in $\mathbb R^2\,.$ Later you wrote $\boldsymbol{r}(t)=\sin(9\theta)\cos(\theta)\boldsymbol{i}+\sin(9\theta)\sin(\theta)\boldsymbol{j}$ about which Ted Shifrin made an important first comment. So: what on earth is your curve?

Comment: I got it Thank you very much